# Scala spark dataframe map sorting as per key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, maps, key-value-observing

```
import spark.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.column

def reverseMap(colName:Column) = map_from_arrays(map_values(colName),map_keys(colName))

val testDF = Seq(("cat",Map("black"->3,"brown"->5,"white"->1)),  ("dog",Map("cream"->6,"black"->5,"white"->2)))

  .toDF("animal","ageMap")

testDF.show(false)

val testDF1 = testDF.withColumn("keySort",map_from_entries(array_sort(map_entries(col("ageMap")))))
```

This code runs fine in spark >3 . I want to run spark<3 .

Comment: Hi! Which versions of Spark have you tried that did and did not work? What is the error that you received?

Comment: I tried with 2.4.5 . I doesn't work . I tried with 3.2.2 . It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I gather that your code was working in v3.2.2 and not in v2.4.5.

Your issue is that `map_entries` does not exist in Spark v2.4.5. You can get the same functionality by extracting the keys and values separately using `map_keys` and `map_values`, and then using `array_zip` to combine them.

The first bit is exactly the same:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def reverseMap(colName:Column) = map_from_arrays(map_values(colName),map_keys(colName))
val testDF = Seq(("cat",Map("black"->3,"brown"->5,"white"->1)), ("dog",Map("cream"->6,"black"->5,"white"->2))).toDF("animal","ageMap")

testDF.show(false)
+------+------------------------------------+
|animal|ageMap                              |
+------+------------------------------------+
|cat   |[black -> 3, brown -> 5, white -> 1]|
|dog   |[cream -> 6, black -> 5, white -> 2]|
+------+------------------------------------+
```

And the difference is in how you define `testDF1`

```
val testDF1 = testDF
  .withColumn("keys", map_keys(col("ageMap")))
  .withColumn("values", map_values(col("ageMap")))
  .withColumn("keySort", map_from_entries(array_sort(arrays_zip(col("keys"), col("values")))))
  .select("animal", "ageMap", "keySort")

testDF1.show(false)
+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|animal|ageMap                              |keySort                             |
+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|cat   |[black -> 3, brown -> 5, white -> 1]|[black -> 3, brown -> 5, white -> 1]|
|dog   |[cream -> 6, black -> 5, white -> 2]|[black -> 5, cream -> 6, white -> 2]|
+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

This code ran successfully on a v2.4.5 spark-shell.